# WPF Broken edges

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I’m experiencing a rather strange problem with WPF. When I place buttons on a form they look fine in design time, they look fine on windows XP but when the application is run on windows 7 the edges become broken.

Here is a screen shot of the normal icons (XP and design time)
[image: Normal Edges]

And here is one with the broken edges (windows 7)
[image: Broken Edges]

Any ideas?

EDIT:

As requested here is the code I use for the button

```
<Button Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="cmdChange_dataset" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Grid Width="120">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/Sales_express_lite_WPF;component/Images/note_to_self_32.png" Stretch="None" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Label Content="Change DataSet" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <Button.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Color="Gray"  />
                </Button.Effect>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Can you post your Button's XAML code?

Comment: @Rachel Code sample added to the original post, thinking about it I should have posted that in the first place

Comment: Maybe is related to this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx

Comment: @Alejandro Martin Yep that did the trick, post it as an answer and I will accept/up-vote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is related to this? 
[Layout Rounding on the WPF Text Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx)

Summary from the blog post:

*WPF’s layout engine frequently gives elements sub-pixel positions. Antialiasing algorithms cause these sub-pixel positioned elements to be rendered over multiple physical pixels after filtering. This can result in blurry lines and other non desirable rendering artifacts. Layout rounding has been introduced in WPF 4.0 to allow developers to force the WPF layout system to position elements on pixel boundaries, eliminating many of the negative side effects of sub-pixel positioning.*

*The attached property* `UseLayoutRounding` *has been introduced to allow layout rounding functionality to be toggled on or off.
This property can either be True or False. The value of this property is inherited by an element’s children.*

```
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="100" Width="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="DarkBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="DarkBlue"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you summarise the blog here - it helps in case the URL changes.