# WPF: Two borders with solid background have a ugly pixel row on top (merging color with parent panel's background)

Tags: wpf

Below there is shown a simple part of my wpf app where you can see two borders (1. and 2.).

[image]

At 3. you can see a lite red line (which is my problem). This line was never (explicitly) defined in xaml code. The red background was only defined in a parental grid and is gleam through at the top of the border element. Below Is my code:

```
<Window 
x:Class="BgColorBug.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
>
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Height="4" Background="#1F1F1F" />

        <Border 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="#777777"
            >
            <WrapPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                >
                <Button Padding="7" Margin="7">Hello</Button>
                <Button Padding="7" Margin="7">World</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When I define fix row heights (instead of the auto value) then the red line is not showing so I think it's a rendering problem (by the side the border from 1. has a red line too).

Answer (score 1):

While I has written my question I found [that article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx) with the solution to my problem.

There must be declared UseLayoutRounding="True" on any grid above the last one (because that value is inherited down).

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

After known the keyword 'LayoutRounding' I found [this Article on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636615/wpf-broken-edges/7645628#7645628) with a similar problem.

After knowing the issue with LayoutRounding=False I don't know what are the benefits from not using it? Maybee performance?
What is the best practise using that flag? In some Microsoft articles they say to set it true on the root element (which is the main window). But if so then I'm wondering why that flag is not true by default.